# Computer shutting down after a few minutes

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard, power-supply, shutdown

**Problem**

My computer just shuts down after a few minutes of running. And it doesn't work again for quite some time.

**What I think is causing the problem**
I am pretty sure that the PSU is at fault. It becomes really hot (though I don't know if that's a problem) and I could smell something in my CPU right after it shut down, which came from the PSU or something near it.

Also, this started happening all of a sudden. I recently started using two monitors but I think my machine is not good enough to run dual monitors because my computer lagged too much. I did disconnect the second monitor right after but maybe it could have destroyed the PSU.

Is there any way to check if it's the PSU that's gone bad? I have another PSU but it's not compatible with the rest of the machine. The PSU is, I think, 3 years old and has worked perfectly well up till now.

**Update**

I've cleaned out all the dust from the CPU. There is nothing visibly wrong with the motherboard either. I ran SpeedFan and this was the result.
[Speed fan results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui6fV.png)
 Do I need to replace the PSU?

Comment: If your PSU is the one having problem, chances are your whole PC won't even turn on. For now it sounds like overheating issue. Either your CPU, or GPU or whatever the motherboard is detecting the temperature has gone too hot and it shuts itself down to ensure it doesn't get damaged. Go to the BIOS of your motherboard and usually there is a section to check the system temperature.. and keep an eye on it to see if it heats up a lot or not. Also if any of your fan are not working.

Comment: The fans are working properly. But what about the smell? It smelled like something was burning.

Comment: That could be dust stuck on the overheating heat sink (or could be dust from inside the PSU). Can you narrow down where do you smell it?

Comment: Almost certain it was near the PSU. I will try running the machine without a graphic card.

Comment: PSU fan is running?

Comment: My CPU is always open and I dont see anything wrong on the motherboard. I took out the fan and cleaned out quite a bit of dust. But after 10 minutes of running the machine I sensed the smell again. And after about 45 minutes, there was a weird sound, I panicked and shut down and saw a little smoke near the PSU.

Comment: Look here:http://www.wikihow.com/Check-a-Power-Supply for the ***`Is there any way to check if it's the PSU that's gone bad?"`***

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui6fV.png the results of the SpeedFan test, do I have to replace the PSU?